# Create a photo booth from library to pick images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

I'm new to xcode. I am trying to create a photo booth which appears at the bottom (as the one in the image) so that i can make multiple selections and view the result at the top. Any knows how this can be achieved? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement UICollectionView for photo booth.

For *UI design* follow the given steps,

1. Create a UIViewController
2. Add UICollectionView on UIViewController
3. Set constraint according to your UI design
4. Set UICollectionCell height and width same and set mini spacing whatever you want in For cells 5 and For lines 5

and for *programming part*,

1. Take data from where you get json parsing or your static data.
2. Store in one array and reload UICollectionView
3. Then assign data to your UICollectionView using their delegates and datasource methods.